# There is no Label when I try to set it programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm new in making UI programatically. I want to create a new View after click at the cell row and display there a Label, but when app goes to that View, there is nothing except for the white screen. Does anyone knows how to resolve my problem?

DetailViewController:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

var data: DataModel!
var firstAndLastNameLabel = UILabel()
let contentView = UIView()
let scrollView = UIScrollView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("DETAIL VIEW CONTROLLER: \(String(describing: data))")
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view.addSubview(firstAndLastNameLabel)
   
    set()
    setFirstAndLastNameLabel()
}

func set() {
    firstAndLastNameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 150, height: 35))
    firstAndLastNameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 260)
    firstAndLastNameLabel.text = "\(data.firstName) \(data.lastName)"
}

func configureFirstAndLastNameLabel() {
    firstAndLastNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating new views programmatically, you also need to add it to some other view as a subview.

In this case it can be your view controller view:

```
view.addSubview(firstAndLastNameLabel)
```

Or you can add your `contentView` to controller view, and then label to `contentView`, depending on your needs. In this case you also need to add frame for `contentView` too.

```
view.addSubview(contentView)
contentView.addSubview(firstAndLastNameLabel)
```

---

A little off-topic. Having static frames is not a good idea at all, because your UI will look completely different on different devices.

The most convenient way is to use layout constraints - the same ones you use in a storyboard. Check out [this article](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/auto-layout-programmatically/) on how to use them programmatically.

If you want to work with raw frames, you have to do it inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`: there you can get the real size of the controller view and calculate the frames for nested views accordingly.

Comment: Everything works now. The Label was hide behind the top bar, so I just changed the top anchor and now is visible. Thanks for help, lesson about UI and article.